# Running Bat From PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've got a script that eventually needs to start a batch file.  The command I'm running is:

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" ".\Batch.bat" -Verb runas
```

When I run this, the Command Prompt window opens, and it opens to the correct folder, but doesn't actually start the batch file.  Once the window opens, I can manually enter:

```
.\Batch.bat
```

and that seems to work from there.  Also, if I try to bypass CMD entirely and run the batch file in PowerShell, it gives me the first three lines that display when I run it in CMD, but doesn't give me the first prompt I need to enter, so that's why I'm trying to do this in a new CMD window.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Please read the output from `cmd.exe /?`, if you, are having issue with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

To run the batch file in an elevated session in a new window that uses the *same working directory as the caller* and *stays open*:

```bash
Start-Process cmd.exe "/k cd `"$PWD`" & .\Batch.bat" -Verb RunAs
```

- Note the use of `/k`, which instructs `cmd.exe` to execute the commands that come after it, and then keeps the session *open* (by contrast, `/c` would *exit* the session after the commands complete, which would automatically *close the window* - run `cmd /?` for details).
- If you try to pass a command *without preceding it with either `/c` or `/k`*, `cmd.exe` effectively *ignores* the command and enters an interactive session, which is what you saw.

To invoke the batch file in an *auto-closing* window in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory, you can invoke it *directly*:

```bash
Start-Process '.\Batch.bat' -Verb RunAs
```

---

##### Background information:

Windows treats batch files (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`) as if they were executables, so you don't necessarily need to invoke them via `cmd.exe` explicitly:

```bash
Start-Process '.\Batch.bat' -Verb RunAs
```

The above is the equivalent of `cmd.exe /c .\Batch.bat`, which means that the batch file executes and the `cmd.exe` session then *exits*, i.e. the window automatically *closes*.

---

If you want to execute the batch file in a `cmd.exe` session that  *stays open*, you must use an *explicit* invocation of `cmd.exe` with `/k` (run `cmd /?` for details):

```bash
Start-Process cmd.exe "/k `"$PWD\Batch.bat`"" -Verb RunAs
```

Note the use of `$PWD` to refer to the *caller's* current directory, which is necessary, because `-Verb RunAs` defaults to `C:\Windows\System32` as the working directory when `-Verb RunAs` is used to invoke *unmanaged* (non-.NET) applications.

That is, [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with `-Verb RunAs`:

- *never* preserves the caller's working directory and *never* honors a `-WorkingDirectory` argument when invoking *unmanaged* (non-.NET) executables, notably including `cmd.exe` / a batch file or [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI (even though the latter is built on top of .NET Framework, the *`.exe` file itself* is unmanaged)
- *does* preserve it / *does* honor `-WorkingDirectory` for *managed* (.NET) executables, notably including [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI (though conceivably there are other executables that set their own working dir. on startup).

---

If you additionally want to preserve the caller's working directory, you must therefore include a `cd` command in your `cmd.exe` call:

```bash
Start-Process cmd.exe "/k cd `"$PWD`" & .\Batch.bat" -Verb RunAs
```

---

**Note**:

- Using the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) to refer to PowerShell's current directory (location)  *typically* works fine, but won't work in two cases:

  - If PowerShell's current [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations) isn't a *file-system* location; e.g., if it is a location on the `HKLM:` *registry* drive.
  - If the current location is a file-system location that is based on a *PowerShell-only drive* (established with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)), which the outside world doesn't know about.
- If either case applies, use the following instead of `$PWD`, which *always* works:

  ```bash
    $((Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath)
  ```

Comment: Start-Process '.\Batch.bat' -Verb RunAs did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$script = "c:\script\Batch.bat"
$workDir = Split-Path $script -Parent
$batscript = Split-Path $script -Leaf
Set-Location -path $workDir
&".\$batscript"
```

Comment: The question shows the use of `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, which means that the batch file should run in an _elevated_ session, which the direct invocation you're showing cannot achieve. If that weren't a concern, direct invocation would be as simple as `.\Batch.bat` (the path-parsing techniques you're showing may be of general interest, but it's not clear how they relate to the question).

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.