# Bat File fails to start powershell script without hard-coded directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file, elevated-privileges

My plan is as follows:

1. Open .bat file
2. File then opens a PS window with script execution allowed and as admin(!)
3. Directory must be variable for it to run on any PC in that folder.
4. Install Chocolatey and Winget for it to install apps.
5. Must be without user input.

My .ps1 File is named `Start.ps1` and the batch file is named `Start.bat`.

In the current batch configuration, it won't execute the PS window as admin, or with script execution allowed.

```bash
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\Install\StartNew.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

It does work when directory is 1:1, but on different machine it doesn't start the install of chocolatey and winget.

Comment: You do know that you could use environment variables in either of the languages. Also be aware that when running elevated, _(runas administrator)_, the current working directory changes to ```\Windows\System32```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Place your `Start.bat` and `Start.ps1` files in the same directory.
- Use the following in `Start.bat`:

```
@echo off & setlocal

:: Determine the full path to the companion .ps1 file (Start.ps1)
:: based on the full path of this batch file (Start.bat)
set "PS1File=%~dpn0.ps1"

:: Now reference %PS1File% as part of the PowerShell command.
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"%PS1File%\"'"
```

Note:

- You'll still get a UAC prompt to authorize creation of an elevated process (which you could only avoid if you deactivated UAC, which is strongly advised against).
- As [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) notes, the elevated process will see `C:\Windows\System32` as its working directory; if your `.ps1` script needs a different one (and doesn't itself change to it), you'll need to switch to a nested `-File` to a nested `-Command` call that invokes `Set-Location` before calling the script.

  - As an aside: If you were to call [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, instead, the *caller's working directory would be preserved* (even if you happen to call *from* Windows PowerShell; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75945004/45375)).
- To fully deactivate the execution policy, use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` rather than `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, as shown above. (It typically won't make a difference in practice, but the latter will *prompt* for scripts that were *downloaded from the web*).
- There's *no* reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly, as in the code above. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.